# How do I propagate an error outside of a closure?

Tags: rust, closures

I've got this little fragment in a function which returns `Result`:

```rust
list.sort_by(|a, b| a.re.partial_cmp(&b.re).unwrap()
                        .then(a.im.partial_cmp(&b.im).unwrap()));
```

but I don't like the unwrap.  I'd rather replace the `.unwrap()` with `?` but that gives me the error:

```
cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `std::cmp::Ordering`
```

How can I propagate the error outside the closure?

Comment: normally, you can return from a closure by using syntax like `|| -> Result<_, _> { ... }`, but [sort_by](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by) requires a function to return an `Ordering`, so you can't change it to handle a `Result`.

Comment: Can't you use `cmp` instead of `partial_cmp`?

Comment: I don't think so, the fields are `f64` (or some type which eventually boils down to f64 anyway) which famously does not implement `Ord`. See: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67417

Comment: https://docs.rs/ordered-float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't indicate an error via the return value of `sort_by`, and you can't abort the sort while it's under way. But you can smuggle the error out by accessing a mutable variable outside of the closure and returning a dummy value:

```rust
let mut failed = false;
list.sort_by(
    |a, b| match (a.re.partial_cmp(&b.re), a.im.partial_cmp(&b.im)) {
        (Some(reo), Some(imo)) => reo.then(imo),
        _ => {
            failed = true;
            Ordering::Equal
        }
    },
);
match failed {
    false => Ok(list),
    true => Err("I think not"),
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1e91cab0b85a575407d8cf7ce7ac9928)

Though I suspect that you'd be better served by

- first looking for NaNs in the list and not sorting at all if there are any (You can keep the unwraps then, as they'll really never occur), or
- use something like [`ordered_float`](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/latest/ordered_float/struct.OrderedFloat.html) (or [`f64::total_cmp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f64.html#method.total_cmp) (stable since 1.62)) to make sure you can always sort (I haven't tried it yet, but it looks nice.)

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try.  Your first bullet is a good idea, except I think it's better to check that all the floats are normal via `is_normal()` IIRC.  There is more than just NaN to worry abt (±∞) and possibly others have to be excluded too. I hadn't heard of `total_cmp` thanks!

Comment: Probably safe to do it that way, indeed. (Though [I can't think](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2d321e20d2cd5f0b27ac130402942167) of any other uncomparable floats beside NaNs.)

Comment: I actually went with your idea of checking that all the list elements were normal first, which makes the unwrap operation safe.